# Hide div when add items - ionic framework

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying to hide specific div (empty state) when i add some item from add button, any ideas how can i do that easily? 
Best Regards, Will.

page.html

```
<ion-content>
      <!-- DIV ABOVE -->
  <div class="center-div">
    <img src="assets/imgs/noItem.svg" />
    <div class="center">
      <h1>Empty List</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh" refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

  <ion-list>
    <button *ngFor="let item of items" ion-item (click)="goToItemDetail(crop)">
      ...
  </ion-list>

  <ion-fab right bottom>
    <button ion-fab class="button-fab" (click)="addItem()">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can hide div with the help of *ngIf="condition"

```html
<div class="center" *ngIf="items">
  <h1>Empty List</h1>
</div>
```

or you can also check boolean varible on button like

```js
// isVisible: boolean
addItem() {
  this.isVisible = false;
}
```

```html
<div class="center" *ngIf="!isVisible">
      <h1>Empty List</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: I use the first option that you mentioned,and yes, the div is hide. But i haven't add any item.

Comment: you need to set this.isVisible after adding item.